# Returning an iterator from a function gives me a weird error

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

So I have my class named Client and it contains a list of strings. I want a method to get an iterator at the beginning and another at the end. So I have the following code:

```
iterator Client::getGustBegin() const { return _gustos.begin(); }
iterator Client::getGustEnd() const { return _gustos.end(); }
```

And in the Client.h it's like this:

```
    iterator getGustBegin() const;
    iterator getGustEnd() const;
```

Also _gustos is declared like this:

```
list<string> _gustos;
```

I'm using g++ compiler and it shows me this error:

```
error: invalid use of template-name 'std::iterator' without an argument list
```

In both of the lines in the Client.h. I have the map and list includes. I don't know why and I don't understand the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An iterator, say from a `std::vector<int>` does not need to be related to `std::iterator`. Also, `std::iterator` is a *class template*, similar to `std::vector`, which requires the use of template arguments to instantiate an actual type from the template.

Comment: std::iterator is a template. You need to provide arguments to the template: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/

Comment: how about returning std::list<std::string>::const_iterator?

Comment: Edited to show how _gustos is declared. @DyP and Ed Plunkett I understand what you mean but I don't know how to do it. I guess I could return a const_iterator but wouldn't it give me the same error?

Comment: @p.bosch `std::list<std::string>::const_iterator` is an actual type, not a template; on the other hand [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) (or just `iterator` if you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere) is a class template, and, strictly speaking, not an iterator (but a class template that helps *creating* iterator types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typedef is often a good thing:

```
class Client
{
   public:
   typedef std::list<std::string>::iterator gust_iterator;
   gust_iterator getGustBegin() const;
};


inline Client::gust_iterator Client::getGustBegin() const {
   return _gustos.begin();
}
```

In your case (as already pointed out) iterator is referring to std::iterator.
(Hence, you gave another example for avoiding 'using nmaespace std')

Comment: Are you sure this will compile with a non-const iterator in a const member function?

Comment: That was it, adapted to my code, but thanks, this helped me solve the problem!

Comment: @DyP No - The OP class declaration is too vague (hence I keep it)